# Importing zipped files in Mysql using CMD

Tags: mysql, database, unix, cmd, 7zip

I am trying to import zipped database files into Mysql using command prompt using the following command

```
7z < backup.sql.7z | mysql -u root test
```

The *root* user *don't* have any *password* associated with it.
***test*** is my target blank database.
I use ***7zip*** for unzipping purpose.
The zipped database i.e. backup.sql.7z is located in D drive.

But it's giving the following error
[image]

So, instead I used the following command

```
7z < backup.7z | mysql -u root test
```

**Note**: This time I am using ***backup.7z*** instead of ***backup.sql.7z***

But then I get the following error
[image]

Clearly there's something wrong with my SQL syntax.

What will be the correct syntax to use then ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to import from a compressed file as well, and stumbled upon your question.
After a bit of messing around, I found that this worked for me:

```
7z x -so backup.7z | mysql -u root test
```

**x** is the extraction command
**-so** makes 7-zip write to stdout

Comment: yes, this one really works.. THANK YOU very much @Wang. Do you have some other workable script which will do the exact work for other types of zip application like winzip, gz etc. ? THANK YOU again.

Comment: Just a note on a trouble I've been struggling with - if you need to supply mysql with a password, using `-p password` doesn't work, you must type it without space: `-ppassword`. Maybe it could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your syntax, it's just a limitation with 7zip. It's better to use xz in this case, which doesn't put extraneous junk in stdout, or directly call the 7z.dll with your favorite programming language. 7z.exe is really meant for archive management, rather than unix-style piping, and Igor is very reluctant to change that.

If you try a plain `7z < somefile.7z` you'll immediately see that all you get back is a usage list.

Comment: I also did **xz −−decompress −−stdout backup.sql.gz | mysql -u root test** but got the error **xz: backup.sql.zip: File format not recognized**

Comment: xz understands .xz. gzip understands .gz. If you're trying to script something to import lots of different backup types, you need to parse the extension; if you're doing it by hand you just need to use the right tool for the job.