# Importing zipped files in Mysql using command line

Tags: mysql, database, cmd, winzip, xz

[Importing zipped files in Mysql using CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11258811/1488173)

What is the right syntax to import sql zipped files into mysql using cmd ?

I am doing the following

```
xz < backup.sql.gz | mysql -u root test
```

But always getting the following error
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I got the answer from my other question. 
This is the command to import zipped file when you are using 7zip

> 7z x -so backup.7z | mysql -u root test

x is the extraction command

`-so` option makes 7-zip write to stdout

Comment: thanks, but it worked for me if -u and username, -p and password, dont have space, hence, 7z x -so backup.7z | mysql -umysqlusername -pmysqlpassword dbname, thx for the hint

Answer (score 80):

Try:

```
unzip -p dbdump.sql.zip | mysql -u root -p yourdbname
```

The dbdump.sql.zip should contain a single SQL file. 
The -p flag pipes the output into the mysql binary.

Comment: you must have installed unzip, you can install unzip, if not installed. `sudo apt-get install unzip`

Comment: @Allahbakash.G - yes, I did have unzip installed... the OP's question did say that their file was **zipped**.

Comment: yeah, while using unzip command in the new ubuntu machine, I had got an error, saying unzip is not installed.

Answer (score 17):

```
zcat backup.sql.gz | mysql -u[username] -p[pswd] [db]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want might to try `xz −−decompress −−stdout` to decompress.

Full command would be `xz −−decompress −−stdout backup.sql.gz | mysql -u root test`

Comment: It's showing an error like->  **xz: backup.sql.zip: File format not recognized**

Comment: xz doesn't seem to support zip files. Only xc and lzma formats.

Comment: Yes, I use it for 7z archives. Should work fine with zip files too. My command line looks like `7z.exe e -y -so current.7z`